# how to get average ratio from an output file

Tags: bash, shell, average

I am making a bash code to get the total of transactions in a server, also including successful and failures, so far this is my output

```
   TOTAL     SUCCESS    FAILED   AVERAGE SUCCESS    AVERAGE FAILED
 =====================================================================
  6139386    2079679    4059707     33.874381         66.125619
```

which is just perfect, it also generates a file for every single event, I mean a file for successful transaction, one for failed transactions and one for all the transactions

Now, from the failed transactions file, I need to get in detail which errors made the transaction fail and their frequency.

I made this code

`cat /tmp/test1.txt | grep "|-1|" | cut -d'|' -f34 > /tmp/test3_1.txt`

`ERR=$(sort test3_1.txt | uniq -c)`

Where test1.txt is the file where the failed transactions are stored and test3_1.txt is the file where the errors are stored

As you can see I saved this output in a variable to be used later, and this is the output

```
82       -11
7241     -4
10040    1
7        10
3115778  1000
146      10002035
```

Where the number in the left is the frequency and the number in the right is the error code

So far this is just what I wanted, but I need to make also an average ratio for each error code based on it's frequency and the total of failed transactions, basically a table like this

```
82      -11       0.002%
7241    -4        0.178%
10040   1         0.247%
7       10        0.000%
3115778 1000      76.749%
146     10002035  0.004%
```

Based on the total of failed transactions (4059707)

Now, what I don't know to do is to select only the left column to make the proper calculations to get the average ratio of each of the errors and show it in the right column.

I got so far this code:

```
for i in $(awk '{print $1}' test3_1.txt) do;
AVEE=$($i * 100 | bc)
```

But it didn't work

Comment: what input do you have, and what output do you want? the sum of 1st column of your cmd's output `!= 4059707`. is it ok? Or I don't understand it correctly.

Comment: the putput I have is the first table (2 columns), and the one that I want is the second (3 columns). The `4059707` is the total of failed transactions

Comment: please explain, from your **first table**, how can I get the number `4059707`?

Comment: It is from a transaction log, It is updating all day and never will be the same, for this example I took one of the outputs I got running the script to test, on the first table, where you have all (Total, Success, Failed, Average success, Average failed) You get the number from the Failed column

Comment: I don't know if you read my first comment. if the sum of the 1st column should ` = 4059707`, your cmd to get the **first table** (the `cat|grep|cut|sort|uniq`) would have problem. because `the sum != 4059707`

Comment: Wait, which one is the **first table** ??? you said it has 2 columns, I thought that would be the `82 -11` etc one.

Comment: Ok the table with 2 columns is not the complete output... that's why you have `sum != 4059707`, now when I said the first table I meant the one with `82 -11` and the second table is the one with `82 -11 0.002%`

Comment: ** so if the first table is complete, the sum of col1 = 4059707? ** this is important, because if you have only one input (the first table), we cannot get the correct total (4059707) from it. The table with 5 columns in fact doesn't make much sense for this question. it provides some background info. P.S. your command line chain could be optimized.

Comment: yep, the complete table gives 4059707, the table with 5 columns is just information for the user. And I'd like to get the code better, any suggestions will be more than welcome P.S I am basically new at Linux and this is my firs script

Comment: ok, I post an answer for u.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one-liner would do the job:

```
 awk '{s+=$1;i[NR]=$1" "$2;a[i[NR]]=$1}END{for(x in i)print i[x],sprintf("%.3f%", 100*a[i[x]]/s)}' file
```

- you could change  `"%.3f%` to get different format.
- if you want to have better output format you could `awk....|column -t`

here is the test:

```
kent$  awk '{s+=$1;i[NR]=$1" "$2;a[i[NR]]=$1}END{for(x in i)print i[x],sprintf("%.3f%", 100*a[i[x]]/s)}' file|column -t
82       -11       0.003%
7241     -4        0.231%
10040    1         0.320%
7        10        0.000%
3115778  1000      99.441%
146      10002035  0.005%
```

**This test was made on the incomplete example given by OP (see comments under the question), the result could be different from OP's output.**

Comment: I tried `awk '{s+=$1;i[NR]=$1" "$2;a[i[NR]]=$1}END{for(x in i)print i[x],sprintf("%.3f%", 100*a[i[x]]/s)}' "$ERR"|column -t` but it didn't work

Comment: @AntonioPerezOseguera your `$ERR` is not file, you cannot do that with awk. you could `echo "$ERR"|awk ...|column -t`

Comment: sorry for the delay, I figured out that it wouldn't worki with a variable after I commented your answer. It is actually working pretty well right now, just, as a favor, could you please explain the code?! I am trying to learn and avoid asking dumb questions like this one